# Character group and homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

The question is that:

- Let $\phi:G\to G'$ be a homomorphism between of abelian groups. Define an induced homomorphism $\hat{\phi}:\hat{G'}\to \hat{G}$ between their character groups. And prove that if $\phi$ is injective, then $\hat{\phi}$ is surjective, and conversely.

I know the induced homomorphism is: $\hat{\phi}(\chi')=\chi'\circ \phi$, and know how to prove if $\phi$ is surjective then $\hat{\phi}$ is injective (but this is not the question asking for).

I tried some approaches of proving the last part, but still not yet finished. Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Are your groups finite?

Comment: Yup, they are finite

Comment: Then the last assertion is equivalent to extending a character from the subgroup $G$ to the whole group $G'$ (viewing $G$ as a subgroup of $G'$). Try to prove this by induction on the order of the subgroup (you can even show that there are $(G':G)$ many such extensions).

Comment: See for example Lemma 3.2 in these [notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/charthy.pdf)

Comment: Oh, actually I overlooked an important fact that make the question much easier. Since if G is abelian then |G^hat|=|G|, and so the answer come out easily because for example if phi is injective then |G|≤|G'| and subjectivity of phi^hat means |G'^hat|≥|G^hat|, now use the fact then we are done!

Comment: No, sorry for it, it still has some mistakes.